# Getting error asInvalidSession id while invoking upsert bulk operation in mule salesforce connector

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Polling app daily once. We are loading data using upsert bulk operation in salesforce. First day it is working fine . Second day on wards we are getting the below error(InvalidSession id ). I found workaround as reconnection strategy and configured even after it is not working.

```
[2017-06-07 10:02:24.519] ERROR   org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier [[test-salesforce-bulk].checkbulkupsert.stage1.05]: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: InvalidSessionId : Invalid session id. Type: class com.sforce.async.AsyncApiException
[2017-06-07 10:02:24.547] ERROR   org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy [[test-salesforce-bulk].checkbulkupsert.stage1.05]: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke upsertBulk.
Element               : /test-salesforce-bulk/processors/4/prepareAccountRequestSubFlow/subprocessors/1 @ test-salesforce-bulk
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
Failed to invoke upsertBulk. (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.parseAndThrowException(BulkConnection.java:180)
  com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.createOrUpdateJob(BulkConnection.java:164)
  com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.createOrUpdateJob(BulkConnection.java:132)
  com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.createJob(BulkConnection.java:122)
  org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceConnector.createJobInfo(SalesforceConnector.java:2570)
  org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceConnector.upsertBulk(SalesforceConnector.java:672)
  org.mule.modules.salesforce.generated.processors.UpsertBulkMessageProcessor$1.process(UpsertBulkMessageProcessor.java:153)
  (50 more...)

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Can you please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

There error says Invalid Session Id.
This means that the initial session has expired.  Check your login history and see if there's even an attempt to login.  If there's not, you need to update your username in Mulesoft.  If there is and it was unsuccessful, you need to update your password/security token.  If there is and it was successful, then it could be that your Session Settings are set to limit calls to the initial IP address or something like that.